# Seek for co-author for motivational theory manuscript

Tags: paper-submission, authorship, motivation, psychology

I am looking for co-authors for my manuscript. I am a sociology student and my dissertation deals with the intersection of sociology and psychology. I have therefore adapted part of it related to Maslow's theory of needs into a purely psychological article and submitted it to a journal, and have received peer-reviewed feedback that it needs to be revised. However, there is too much psychology-related knowledge involved that I have not been exposed to, so I am looking for possible psychology co-authors here.

The article deals with the reinterpretation of the concepts of psychological egoism and motivation to improve Maslow's theory of needs. The revisions are mainly directed to involve more previous psychological theories, including psychodynamics, evolutionary psychology, etc. to better interpret motivation. Feel free to contact me if interested!

Comment: "How do I find co-authors?" is a legitimate question within the scope of Academie SE. "Please be my co-author" is not.